# 3d mesh won't parent to rig, model faceplants forward

Tags: modeling, rigging, rigify

I'm trying to do a simple character rig. Everything goes fine until I try to parent the mesh to the generated rig using automatic weights. Then the model faceplants into the floor, leaving behind the armature and generated rig. Prior to adding the armature, I used the Merge by Distance option in
Edit Mode to remove excess vertices. I've gone through some older threads on here but can't find a solution.

Before parenting:
[image]
After parenting:
[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: first thing unparent the object with Alt P > Keep Transform, because if it's already parented to something else it will come back to its default rotation

Comment: Can you show the 'item' entry for the model on the N panel. It sounds as if the rotation may not have been applied to it. Also check @moonboots answer first!

Comment: Somehow got it to work. So now it's pose-able. I couldn't figure out how it worked so I rerigged it and followed the steps you suggested. Now it's working. Thanks for your help. :)